# How to save string with sprintf from list viewed recursively

Tags: c, string, list, printf, buffer

I want to return a char* pointer with the string produced by this code:

```
    char *printFilmRating(char *buffer, struct rating_film *handler) {
       if(handler!=NULL) {
          sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "Valutazione inserita il %02d/%02d/%d alle %02d:%02d:%02d\n",handler->date_rating->day,handler->date_rating->month,handler->date_rating->year,handler->date_rating->hour,handler->date_rating->minutes,handler->date_rating->seconds);
          sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "Valutatore: %s\n",handler->nickname);
          sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "Valutazione: %f\n",handler->rate_film);
          sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "Commento:\n%s\n",handler->text);
          sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "\n");
          buffer=printFilmRating(buffer, handler->next);
          }
       return buffer;
    }
```

Practically, this function will read a list since the list pointer is not null. But at the end of the function, the function will return a (null) string, I think because it will return the first instance on stack, that had (null). How can I return all the information red from the list?

Comment: Is there any reason you use multiple chained `printf`-statements, beside making things slower? Also, how do you guarantee the buffer is big enough?

Comment: This code has a number of problems but returning a null string should not be one of them. Please show the erroneous output and full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is too big for a comment and it may in fact answer your question, here's something for you.

I compiled the following code successfully (using `gcc -std=c99`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sample {
    struct sample *next;
    int value;
};

char *printSample(char *buf, struct sample *handle){
    // effectively the same code as OP
    if( handle ){
        sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Value: %d\n", handle->value);
        buf=printSample(buf, handle->next);
    }
    return buf;
}

int main(){
    char buffer[400] = {""}; // NOTE: initialize string to nulls
    struct sample mysample = { .next = 0, .value = 1 };
    struct sample mysample1 = { .next = &mysample, .value = 2 };
    struct sample mysample2 = { .next = &mysample1, .value = 3 };
    struct sample mysample3 = { .next = &mysample2, .value = 4 };
    printf("%s\n", printSample(buffer, &mysample3));
    return 0;
}
```

and I got the following output:

```
Value: 4
Value: 3
Value: 2
Value: 1
```

Which is to be expected. The code you posted isn't efficient or necessarily safe but it should work. If the output isn't what you want you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but I had found the real error, not related to the function, but related to his declaration in a library. Instead of char *nameFunction() the declaration on a single line was char nameFunction().